# Parsing RSS file with zend 2 feed , i cant get media tag

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I just can't seem to be able to solve this. I want to get the media:thumbnail from an RSS file . using ZF2 ; Zend\Frame a follow the manual but i cant get images from the xml file , any idea plz :)

that the controller Code :

```
<?php

namespace RSS\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Feed\Reader as feed;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction(){

        try{

            $rss =            feed\Reader::import('http://www.wdcdn.net/rss/presentation/library/client/skunkus/id/cc3d06c1cc3834464aef22836c55d13a');
        }catch (feed\Exception\RuntimeException $e){
            echo "error : " . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

       $channel = array(
            'title'       => $rss->getTitle(),
            'description' => $rss->getDescription(),
            'link'        => $rss->getLink(),
            'items'       => array()
        );

        foreach($rss as $item){
            $channel['items'][] = array(
                'title'       => $item->getTitle(),
                'link'        => $item->getLink(),
                'description' => $item->getDescription(),
               // 'image'       => $item->getImage(),
            );
        }

        return new  ViewModel(array(
            'channel' => $channel
        ));
    }


}
```

Comment: Now i can get title, description by using these methods : $channel->getTitle() and $channel->getDescription but for media i can't do something like that.

that the link of the manual that i readed : 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.feed.reader.html

Comment: Then: have you tried - as mentionend in your link to the documentation - the `getImage()` function?

Comment: yes but it's gives me this err msg : 

Method: getImage does not exist and could not be located on a registered Extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hi**

for who get the same pb i solve it by adding a new function to Zend/Feed/Reader/Entry/rss.php called getMedia() , that the code for who has a better idea or a better code i'll be thankful if you help :

```
    public function getMedia()
{
    if (array_key_exists('media', $this->data)) {
        return $this->data['media'];
    }

    $media = null;

    if ($this->getType() == Reader\Reader::TYPE_RSS_20) {
        $nodeList = $this->xpath->query($this->xpathQueryRss . '/media:thumbnail');

        if ($nodeList->length > 0) {
            $media = new \stdClass();
            $media->url    = $nodeList->item(0)->getAttribute('url');

        }
    }
    $this->data['media'] = $media;

    return $this->data['media'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Did not have the time to dig through it I just needed the image

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it without having to extend or modify the class:

```
foreach ($channel as $item) {
    $xmlItem = $item->saveXml();
    $xmlFeed = new \SimpleXMLElement($xmlItem);
    $thumbAttr = $xmlFeed->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/')->thumbnail->attributes();
    $thumbUrl = (string)$thumbAttr['url'];
}
```